# How to connect to SQL Server database not on my network?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have received SQL Server infos that looks like this:

- DB Server: `abc\xyz`
- Login: `sa`
- Password: `12345`
- Database: `MyDB`

Now, I do not have server abc's access directly but I can ping it like this:

```
abc.def.company.com
```

How can I connect to the server using SQL Server Management Studio from my local machine?

Comment: In a rare case database server will open to public (most cases it's hiding behind firewall). Suggested way is: Deploy server side script to the server to read the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to connect to `abc.def.company.com\xyz`

In SQL Server you need to provide `servername\instancename` in order to connect to a specific database. Usually the `instancename` is omitted when the instance that is running on `servername` is the default one.

Answer (score 1):

| How can I connect to the server using MS SQL Management Studio from my local machine?

The exact same way like to one on your network.

THAT IS - after making sure you can reach your network. Now, if the admins on the other side do not have some really unusual setup or are total idiots (and yes, that is how it is) then the server will not be reachable via an internet address (the unusual setup would be one that has to be reachable, but this is unusual).

This means that normally you will have to set up a VPN of some sort, which they should have told you how to do. At least NONE of the machines I know of and worked with would be reachable by some dude on the internet - they are all on internal networks.